# Run python script as service, needed virtualenv (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, server, virtualenv

I need to leave running a Python script in a remote server. All OK so far. The problem is I need using `virtualenv` because I have no `sudo` privileges and I only can install and use `pip` packages using `virtualenv`. To ripple the curl, my script need a docker container running, so it's needed two terminals running.

I access through `ssh` and I can run it, but execution keeps attached to my terminals. I've tried using background execution but docker container ignore it and Python script stops when I close terminal. I also tried to put all my instructions (boot docker container, activate `virtualenv` and then run Python script) in a bash script but it neither works, I get the following error activating `virtualenv`:

`source: not found`

The question is: is there any way to leave my script running as daemon or service?

(There is no problem with privileges, I can ask admin for doing all needed steps)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) and [python-service](https://python-service.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) packages that you may use to create python-based daemons and/or services.

Though I suppose it might be enough just to use `nohup python path/to/script.py &`.

Comment: Yep! It seems `nohup` is just I'm looking for. Thanks a lot Linards Kalvans!!